# multi region apache kafka and zookeeper in autoscaling group in AWS

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have searched the web for architecture pointing to setting up apache kafka/zookeeper combo in an autoscaling group in multiple regions in AWS.

Anyone able to setup something like this? Any challenges and solution to those challenges faced. Also what compromises came with that type of setup, if any?

The big problem with auto scaling is to be able  to update configurations files dynamically. AWS is also not able to help because even with using created network interfaces (eni) no way to control launch configuration to utilize enis when using auto scaling groups.

Also how do you manage changing configuration files?

Just have these questions and no where else i can think of to post a question like this. If this is wrong place please let me know and please suggest a place to post a question like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Auto scaling is not a great idea for zookeeper and it can be tricky for Kafka brokers as well. However other Kafka components, like Kafka Streams work great with auto scaling.

Confluent has some tools to help including AWS Cloud Formation templates, an Auto-data balancing tool, and a lot of recommendations for how to setup AWS availability zones (with rack awareness) and regions (with Replicator).

See this blog about the best practices https://www.confluent.io/blog/design-and-deployment-considerations-for-deploying-apache-kafka-on-aws/

See this QuickStart for deployment templates https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/confluent-platform/

Comment: what do you mean by tricky for kafka brokers but possible with kafka streams? isn't kafka stream just a way to read and write data to kafka broker? is broker and streams separate parts of kafka? i mean arent the different features all bundled into the kafka cluster?

Comment: No Kafka Streams is all bundled in a library that runs inside your Streams application. Streams apps connect remotely to the brokers and run on separate machines. Kafka Streams is defined for super easy auto scaling and Streams apps often run as microservices which can increase or decrease the number of instances according to load

Comment: @HansJespersen could you please refer to some resource that shows how to use Streaming capabilities to replicate across geo-locations across multiple-or-two different clusters?

Comment: good whitepaper on replication for DR here https://www.confluent.io/white-paper/disaster-recovery-for-multi-datacenter-apache-kafka-deployments/ and the Confluent Replicator docs are here https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-replicator/index.html